# What do I make of all classification scores being equal to 1?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, cross-validation, score

I've built an XGBoost classifier on a dataset that has 51 columns and a 1000 rows with following code:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

xgbc = XGBClassifier()  
xgbc.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = xgbc.predict(X_test)  

rep = metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)  
print(rep)
```

And I get the scores as follows.
[image]

Then I performed 5 fold cross-validation:

```
cross_val_score(xgbc, X, y, cv=5)
```

And got the following cv scores.

```
1.0
1.0
0.99497487
0.98994975
0.98492462
```

I'm fairly new to machine learning, and I can't figure out if my model is peforming excellently or if it has overfit.

Note: In the training data(X), 10-50% of all values in most feature columns are missing. I did not impute the missing values as tree algorithms are robust to missing values.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, I think your model works fine. Since you hold the test set separate from training, overfitting would reduce the accuracy of the test set, which is not the case. You may want to try the model with a more complex dataset, or play around with the random state or test size in the train-test split to see if the accuracy changes.

And of course, since I do not know what data you are using, check again if there is any variable in the feature set X that is highly correlated with the target variable y. This could lead to an unwanted spillover from X to y.